# Em java, um Void que faz uma soma, retorna valor?

Tags: java, return, void

Minha dúvida fica sobre o que é exatamente um retorno em java. Pois penso que a resposta da soma seria um tipo de retorno, isso é correto?

```
void soma (int a, int b) {
     int s = a + b;
     System.out.println (s);
}
```

Comment: void na Assinatura significa nenhum retorno.

Comment: Void não retorna valor, poderia explicar melhor sua dúvida?

Comment: no algoritmo que você escreveu ele apenas escreve o valor, e não retorna já que é um método void.

Comment: Você quer uma forma de retornar o valor mesmo sendo void,  ou você não esta entendendo porque o valor não esta sendo retornado?

Comment: Certo, então minha dúvida fica sobre o que é exatamente um retorno em java. Pois penso que a resposta da soma seria um tipo de retorno. Perdoe minha ignorância.

Comment: O retorno é algo q vc pode aproveitar ou seja  todo o processamento é feito e na chamada da função pega só a parte que interessa. Imprimir no console não é um retorno. Por exemplo `int total = soma(10, 5); if(total > 7){  System.out.println ("aprovado");}else{ System.out.println ("exame");}`. O retorno da função que foi atribuido à `total` foi usado para algo um decisão no caso.

Comment: Ah sim, cara muito obg. Perfeito mano. Valeu pelo esclarecimento.

Comment: Resumindo, pra um retorno ocorrer é necessário `return`, logo seu método não tem `return`, então não existe retorno.

Answer (score 9):

```
void soma (int a, int b) {
     int s = a + b;
     System.out.println (s);
}
```

Isso aí em cima é um método, que é um tipo de função ou subrotina. A primeira linha diz que

1. O tipo de retorno é `void`, ou seja, o método não retorna valor
2. O nome do método é soma
3. Os argumentos que ele pode receber são dois inteiros, `a` e `b`.

O resultado da soma não é um retorno, é só o resultado da soma :) Ele pode, por exemplo, ser impresso na tela de dentro do próprio método, como você fez. Se o método vai retornar esse valor, ele precisaria ter uma assinatura diferente, explicitando que retorna um inteiro:

```
int soma (int a, int b) {
     return a + b;
}
```

Repare que agora ele diz que retorna um `int`, e de fato faz isso por meio da palavra-chave `return`. Se o método não tem return, ele necessariamente é do tipo `void`. Se tem `return`, a assinatura precisa indicar o tipo do valor que será retornado. E esse retorno é sempre um retorno para quem chama. Por exemplo:

```
int resultado = meuObj.soma(2, 3); // variável resultado receberá valor 5
```

Comment: Ótimo, muito esclarecedor. Muito obrigado.

Comment: E também é claro que um método `void` pode ter um `return` desde que ele não tenha valor.